# AWS EMR: Is it possible to re-use a terminated cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce

I create a cluster. I finished my job and then I terminated the cluster. I want to know that is it possible to re-use this terminated cluster in the future? If no, is there anyway to delete the terminated clusters?

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the cluster by using [clone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/clone-console.html).
As of today, there is no way to delete the terminated clusters from the list.

Comment: Does cloning the cluster copy the files as well (files downloaded using bootstrap actions)?

Comment: It clones the bootstrap actions, which ensures that any files downloaded by those actions in the original cluster will also be downloaded in the cloned cluster.